# Trouble connecting to the Internet using MDS from a Blackberry (works fine in the Simulator)

Tags: java, http, blackberry, java-me

I have some code to connect to the internet, it works fine in the simulator
but when I try it on a real device, I always get a 400 http response code
(the response body says "Connection timed out")

I'm using JRE 5
and using Blackberry 9000 on OS version 5 for both the real device and the simulator.

It is activated according to Advanced Options > Enterprise Activation 
Is there something else I need to change on the real device to make it work?

I slowly whittled down my code to get to the root of the issue
and I'm down to this code:

```
package mypackage;

import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;

import net.rim.device.api.io.transport.TransportInfo;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class MyApp extends UiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyApp theApp = new MyApp();
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public MyApp() {
        pushScreen(new SimpleScreen());
    }
}

class SimpleScreen extends MainScreen {
    public SimpleScreen() {
        this.setTitle("Hello");
        ConnectionThread ct = new ConnectionThread();
        ct.start();
    }
}

class ConnectionThread extends Thread {
    private static String url = "http://www.wikipedia.org/";
    public void run() {

        System.out.println(" -- ConnectionThread.run()");
        System.out.println(" ---- MDS hasSufficientCoverage? " + TransportInfo.hasSufficientCoverage(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_MDS));
        try {
            HttpConnection httpConn;
            httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);

            final int iResponseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Dialog.alert("Response code: " + Integer.toString(iResponseCode));
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println(" -- /ConnectionThread.run()");
    }
}
```

==============================================

// EDIT:
I'm pretty sure its a device config issue now, I just the [Network Diagnostic Tool](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Network_Diagnostic_Tool.html?nodeid=1450596&vernum=0) and it also returns a 400 HTTP Response with the message "connect timed out".

==============================================

//EDIT #2:
I just tried options->mobile network->diagnostics test
Here are the results:

```
ICMP Ping Echo: No
------
Blackberry Registration: Yes
Connected to Blackberry: Yes
Blackberry PIN-PIN: Yes
------
Server Name: <my enterprise server>
Email Address: <my email>
Connected to <my email>: Yes
```

Then I tried options->mobile network->tools->ping

and pinged google and wikipedia and both say `A network error occurred`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the BES Admin and he says its Docomo issue.. and he has taken it up with them.

Basically there's no code problem (as far as I can tell)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your BB device is connected to any BES server?  I would suggest that you first try to access internet from BB browser.

Comment: Im not 100% sure its connected to the BES, thats what I want to find out. The internet works fine inside the BB Browser. Email also works so its connecting to something over the internet.

Comment: Better to check with your BES administrator. There may be some configuration at BES side.

Comment: any idea what config on a BES might cause a 400 HTTP response from a Java app but not from the web browser?

Comment: I've no idea abt BES. One more thing I can suggest (prob shooting in dark) that you install any third party app on your bb device that accesses internet. And check whether the problem is in your app or device. Edit: Have you gone through this post. You may find something useful here.  http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Connecting-your-BlackBerry-http-and-socket-connections-to-the/td-p/206242